# Space-like pion electromagnetic form factor

Tags: special-relativity, scattering

The 1986's publication "A measurement of the space-like pion electromagnetic form factor" (http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(86)90437-2) starts with:

> The pion form factor has been measured in the space-like $q^2$ region
>   $0.014$ to $0.26 (GeV/c)^2$ by scattering $300 GeV$ pions from the
>   electrons of a liquid hydrogen target.

The process under consideration is the elastic scattering of a charged pion with an electron. They conventionally refer to $q^2$ for a space-like photon momentum and to $t=-q^2$ for a time-like photon momentum.

Why does this energy range for the photon correspond to being "space-like"?

As far as I know one can only talk about being "space-like/time-like/light-like" for the separation of two space-time points or events (in 4D Minkowski space). What would be the two points here?

What energy would be the time-like regime for $q^2$ in the context of 300 GeV pions used to measure the e.m. form factor?

Comment: You can of course talk about a spacelike distance, but more generally it refers to a spacelike vector. In -+++, a timelike vector has negative Minkowski norm. A spacelike one has positive norm.

Comment: @0celo7 That's an answer. Why not post it as one.

Comment: @dmckee: I'm not sure how it pertains to this question though. If the four-momentum is not null, then the photon has to be virtual. I'm not sure what the physical meaning of space-like energy is.

Comment: Of course, one can also talk about a vector being space/time/light-like; same as two points in a vector space always define a vector, namely the one pointing from the first to the second point.

Comment: I believe the vector $q$ connects the first scattering vertex (incoming pion, photon, outgoing pion) with the second vertex (incoming e, photon, outgoig e). Thus, the question is, why is this energy range considered as being space-like?

Comment: The vector $q$ is defined as the momentum transfer originating from the scattered pion $q_\mu=k_\mu-k'_\mu$ with $k$ and $k'$ the pion 4-momentum before and after the scattering. Not sure if that helps..

Comment: Digging more into this I now believe that referring to "spacelike" ($q^2<0$) just means that they are talking about scattering. Later in the article they refer to the timelike ($q^2>0$) range and this is no longer a scattering process. The $q^2>0$ region generally means annihilation processes. Although here more questions arise. How do you measure the pion FF in the timelike region, i.e. when there's by definition no scattering..?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that by saying

> in the space-like $q^2$ region $0.014$ to $0.26 GeV^2$

the authors meant that they are talking about scattering here. It's not this particular energy region that makes it spacelike. More generally one knows that in scattering the momentum transfer is negative $q^2<0$. This means $q$ is a spacelike vector.